# Count occurences in a object using where and count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm using includes in saving the result in a variable.

```
@users = User.where(:id => Issue.select(:author_id).map(&:author_id))
@release_users = ReleaseUser.includes(@users).order('user_id')
```

In `ReleaseUser` table I have some fields as: `id`, `user_id`, `release_id`....

I need to make some calculates in a view.

Example:

```
<%= @release_users.find { |release_user| release_user.id == 2 }.user_id %>
```

Now, I need to count the occurrences in this table for each user.

I tried:

```
<%= @release_users.where(:user_id => 1).count %>
<%= @release_users.where(user_id => 1).count %>
```

But I can't, please, sorry for my English.

Thanks

--UPDATE--
The result of:

```
<% @release_users.each do |release_user| %>
  user_id: <%= release_user.user_id %>
  release_id: <%= release_user.release_id %>
  <br>
<% end %>
```

is

user_id: 85 release_id: 1 
user_id: 66 release_id: 1 
user_id: 94 release_id: 1 
user_id: 254 release_id: 1 
user_id: 52 release_id: 1 
user_id: 263 release_id: 2 
user_id: 90 release_id: 2 
user_id: 73 release_id: 2 
user_id: 56 release_id: 2 
user_id: 43 release_id: 2 
user_id: 196 release_id: 2 
user_id: 183 release_id: 2

UPDATE 02 - Error message

```
ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError in User_reports#index

Showing    /var/www/base2_crowdtest/relatorios/ultimo/trunk/app/views/user_reports/_second_tab.html.erb where line #28 raised:

 #<User id: 2, contact_id: 2, system_role_id: 1, system_idiom_id: 1, status_id: 2, company_id: nil, username: "jose.mario", email: "", opt_in: nil, password_hash: "", password_salt: "", auth_token: "", oauth_token: nil, oauth_expires_at: nil, provider: nil, uid: nil, password_reset_token: nil, password_reset_sent_at: nil, last_login_at: "2014-02-28 18:13:47", created_at: "2012-03-02 21:43:08", updated_at: "2014-02-28 18:13:47">
Extracted source (around line #28):

25: 
26: <%= @release_users.group(:user_id).count %>
27: 
28: 
29: 
30: <div id="details" class="active display-fields">
31:
```

UPDATED 03 - ReleaseUser model

```
class ReleaseUser < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :release, touch: true # para invalidar o cache de contagem de testadores
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role, class_name: 'ReleaseRole'

  attr_accessible :user, :user_id, :role, :role_id
  attr_readonly :release_id, :user_id
```

Comment: Please explain "But I can't". Are you getting an error when you attempt `@release_users.where(:user_id => 1).count`? And are you trying to count just one user, or are you trying to get a collection of counts for all users?

Comment: Hi, yes, I'm getting an error: undefined local variable or method `user_id' for #<#<Class:0x007f57be4360d0>:0x007f57be4156f0>, I'm trying to get the count user by user, example: user_id: 2, count: 3 | user_id: 3, count: 7 ...

Comment: Before I'm doing this: ReleaseUser.where(:user_id => 2).count, but I'm  trying increase the perfomance, so, I'm trying to use includes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish in that last code snippet, but if you want to count each user, do the following:

```
<%= @release_users.group(:user_id).count %>
```

Alternatively:

```
 <% counts = @release_users.group(:user_id).count %>
```

This groups the records by user_id, then counts each group. In the second example, you can access individual counts of items with e.g. `counts[2]` giving you the user count for the user with id 2.

Source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

EDIT: This code snippet will output each user's count in a table. Try to see if you still get a configuration error.

```
 <table>
    <% counts = @release_users.group(:user_id).count %>
    <td>
    <% counts.each do |userid,count| %>
      <tr><%= userid %></tr>
    <% end %>
    <td>
    </table>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I tried do this now and doesn't work, the error is: ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError ... #<User id: 2, contact_id: 2,...

Comment: Do you mind posting the entire error message in the question? Thanks.

Comment: Updated my answer. The ConfigurationError might be unrelated, but try with the new code snippet I posted.

Comment: Thanks again, well, shows the same error, the problem is this line: counts = @release_users.group(:user_id).count

Comment: I see. Do you have a ReleaseUser model in your application?

Comment: When you declare `@release_users`, are you trying to eager load the `Users` table? If so, this is the correct way to do it: `@release_users = ReleaseUser.includes(:user).order('user_id')`
includes() expects a symbol with an association name, not a variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
@release_users.group(:user_id).count
```

This will give you a hash with user_id as key and count as value

```
{1 => 2, 2 => 4}
```